# envio de correo laravel , usando leter y carbon para reducir el tiempo en el evento. aun tarda 5 seg en hacer el insert

Tags: laravel, email, carbon

cuando inserto sin mandar correo se hace en 1 seg y con correo 5 seg , aun teniendolo en el evento.
antes lo use directo en  el controlador de leads y ahora en el evento para evitar ese retraso aun no lo consigo.

ese evento lo uso para crear un log de errores y informacion de leads como eliminar o editar.

Corregido con un job.

es muy interesante que podamos mandar el trabajo despues de mostrar la respuesta https.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Lead;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Mail\correo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
class ProcessLeads implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;



    protected $lead;
 

     

    public function __construct(Lead $lead)
    {
        $this->lead = $lead;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
   
        $lead = $this->lead;
        $mailData = [
            'titulo' => 'nuevo lead:',
            'Email' => $lead->correo,
            'nombre' => $lead->nombre,
            'url' => 'http://crm.vacationcards.com/'
        ];
        
             Mail::to($lead->correo[])->send(new correo($mailData));
        
      
       
    }
}
```

en el controlador agregamos : dispatchAfterResponse

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate(Lead::$rules);
//aqui se creara la nota
        $lead = Lead::create($request->all()); 
        $lead->save();
    

        ProcessLeads::dispatchAfterResponse($lead);


        $leads = new Leads_distribuidor();
        $leads->user_name = $request->input('username2');
        $leads->nombre = $request->input('nombre');
        $leads->edad = $request->input('edad');
        $leads->estadocivil = $request->input('estadocivil');
        $leads->telefono1 = $request->input('telefono1');
        $leads->telefono2 = $request->input('telefono2');
        $leads->correo = $request->input('correo');
        $leads->pais = $request->input('pais');
        $leads->notal = $request->input('notal');
        $leads->created_at2 = $request->input('created_at2');
        $leads->id_lead = $lead->id;
       $leads->save();
```

Comment: Cómo lo llamás a ese evento?  Creo que hay una manera de que lo haga después del request, fijate en la doc. Igual lo ideal sería que lo mandes a una cola y lo proces un Job

Comment: escucho el evento y cada que pasa algo en el modelo ejecuto el log.  ahora loa cambie cree un observador de lead y cada que se crea un lead tambien manda el correo , sigue igual para hacer la redireccion de la pagina tarda minimo 5 seg . checare lo de los job . creo es la solucion , y ause  el controladror de lead , use el modelo de lead y use el listener de lead y todos se hacen en minimo 5 seg.

Comment: gracias ya quedo.

Comment: lo que intentas en php no se puede ... simpre que envies un correo php esperara a una respues de error o success del systema de correo ... a menos que laravel haya incluido esa prop recientemente...